# considering I can start a debugging with --debugger, can I turn it off after I've started the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

Say I start a console with --debugger. Can I then turn off the debugger option somehow? I know there are workarounds (putting an @debug_on field in your code, for instance) but it seems like I should be able to turn the debugger off and on at will from within the console. MY research says that that is not possible.

If the answer is no, do you think it'd be easy enough to do that I could submit a pull request to the Rails code to make it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `--debugger` option just requires the "debugger" gem, you could try to unload/unrequire the library. There are resources that will help you with this, just use Google. It will generally mean [removing](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-remove_const) all of the constants defined by the library.